# Multiple roots in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: field-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let f(x) ∈ $\mathbb{Z}$[x], a polynomial of degree n.  Suppose f(x) has n distinct roots $a_1, ..., a_n$ ∈ $\mathbb{C}$.  Now, with a given f(x), we call a prime *p* "bad" if f(x) has a multiple factor when considered in $\mathbb{Z}_p$[x].  One example is $x^2 + x - 8$ when considered in $\mathbb{Z}_3$[x], where we have $(x+2)^2$.  Now, given f, I need to show that there can only be a finite number of bad primes.

So far I have shown that for quadratics, we only have a double root when p divides the discriminant, and thus we only have a finite number of possibilities, including zero.

I am now having trouble showing what happens when we have cubics and higher orders.

Comment: You are more or less done. There is a notion of discriminant for higher order polynomials that fills the same role. That is, the polynomial has a multiple root iff the discriminant is zero.  It is also well behaved when you reduce mod $p$.

Comment: Out in the world, as opposed to in school, $\mathbb Z_p$ most often refers to the $p$-adic integers, not to the finite field $\mathbb Z/p=\mathbb F_p$. This wouldn't matter much, except that there are similar questions about the two, so a title with the red herring in it is unfortunate...

Answer (score 0):

Given two polynomials, if we want them to have a root in common, then their coefficients should satisfy a condition, higher the degree the more complicated this *resultant polynomial* (as it involves more and more coefficients.

Multiple roots for a polynomial $f$  means it is of them form $f(x) = (x-a)^2g(x)$. Working with real coefficients, and using calculus, differentiating this equation shows that the derivative $f'(x)$ has also the same number *a* as a root.

That is, having a  common root with its derivative is the same as having a multiple root.  Resultant polynomial Res$\,(f,f')$ is the discriminant polynomial.

Now coming to mod $p$ coefficients discriminant being a multiple of $p$ is the condition. Any single number can be a multiple for only a finite number of prime numbers. To know about resultant of a polynomial books written in 19th century are the best than any books on *modern algebra*. Books on Galois theory and field theory written in classical explicit style  could also contain this material.